# NoMethodError in Dishings#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new to coding in general. I'm trying to bolster my skills by creating a web app that allows people to rank their favorite restaurants for particular dishes (e.g. top restaurants for hamburgers).

I'm currently working on a *join table* that links restaurants and dishes. I am trying to add `select_tags` to select one dish from the *dish table* and one restaurant from the *restaurant table*. I'm getting a `NoMethodError`. Would appreciate any insight into my mistakes. Thanks!

error:

> NoMethodError in Dishings#new
>   Showing /Users/frederick7/code/Appdev/pear_review/app/views/dishings/new.html.erb

where line #27 raised:

> undefined method `map' for #

Extracted source (around line #27):

```
</label>

<%= select_tag(:restaurant_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@dishing, 'id', 'restaurant_id', @dishing.id) ) %>
</div>

<!-- Label and input for dish_id -->
```

Here is relevant code in views/dishings/new.html.erb:

```
<!-- Label and input for restaurant_id -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="restaurant_id" class="control-label">
      Restaurant
    </label>
    <%= select_tag(:restaurant_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@dishing, 'id', 'restaurant_id', @dishing.id) ) %>
  </div>

  <!-- Label and input for dish_id -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="dish_id" class="control-label">
      Dish
    </label>
    <%= select_tag(:dish_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@dishing, 'id', 'dish_id', @dishing.id) ) %>
  </div>
```

Here is possibly relevant code from dishings_controller.rb:

```
def new
  @dishing = Dishing.new
end

def create
  @dishing = Dishing.new
  @dishing.restaurant_id = params[:restaurant_id]
  @dishing.dish_id = params[:dish_id]

  if @dishing.save
    redirect_to "/dishings", :notice => "Dishing created successfully."
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: `.map` is for a collection, `options_from_collection_for_select` takes in a collection and call `.map` on it, but `@dishing` is not a collection

Answer (score 0):

As I saw that you are using @dishing which is not an array and options_from_collection_for_select require array or collection.

And one more thing that I notice that you are creating view for new action, and that may probably uses @dishing = Dishing.new in controller.

and if you are fetching restaurant_id and dish_id than not possible

Comment: Doesn't this command create the dishing array?:  'def create
    @dishing = Dishing.new'

Comment: No this command will not creating any array. This will only create a new object of Dishing class.